# How to combine "Values" and "Combine"?

Tags: c++, c++17, googletest

I want to add some special set of values to cartesian product. Something like this:

```
INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P(Test, Test, 
    testing::Values(
        testing::Combine(
            testing::Values(1, 2, 3), 
            testing::Values("one", "two", "three")),
        testing::Values(std::make_tuple(12345, "big value"))));
```

But it's not working. Is there any other working way to do it?

Comment: "it is not working" - please give error messages, a [mcve], and/or what behaviour *exactly* is wrong.

Comment: It's not question, it's my attempt to solve it. Read carefully

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do two instantiations:

```
INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P(TestSanity, Test, 
    testing::Combine(
        testing::Values(1, 2, 3), 
        testing::Values("one", "two", "three")));

INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P(TestSpecial, Test, 
    testing::Values(std::make_tuple(12345, "big value")));
```

Only `Combine()` accepts other generators as input, but that would be undesirable. However, the problem can be easily solved by using two separate macro calls, producing two test suites out of your tests. [See it online](https://godbolt.org/z/rMMeh8).